# Adding multiple text fields with the same code

Tags: ios

I want to be able to add between 1 and 20 text fields to my view with the same code.

My idea is to use a for loop and every time add a text field so the first time it loops it adds "textField1" and the second time it adds "textField2" etc.

I'm not sure how I would go about coding this so I'm looking for your help.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything because I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

for 20 textfields you need to take them in UIScrollView .. you can do like this --

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];

[scrollView setDelegate:self];

//initialize a textfield array;

NSMutableArray *textFieldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//x, y for first textfield in UIScrollView

float x = 20;

float y = 20;

For(int i=1;i<21;i++)
{
   UITextfield *textField = [[UITextfield alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,200,30)];
   textfield.tag = i;
   [textField setDelegate:self];

   //Add Textfield to array just for futureRefrence

   [textFieldArray addObject:textField];

   //Add textfield in UIScrollView

   [scrollView addSubview:textField];

   //Now iterate Y , So they won't over each other

   y = y+50;

}

//Now set ScrollView ContentSize 

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake:(320,20*y)];

//Now Finally Add ScrollView in UIView

[self.view addSubView:scrollView];
```

Also remember declare there delegate in .h file .
and you can access these textfield by the array you put them in ,For Example

If you want a value from textfield three , you can do like this

```
UITextfield *textfield = (UITextfield *)[textFieldArray objectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"text of textField 3 is -- %@",textfield.text);
```

Comment: Ya it is , just do not want to confuse user .

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    UITextField *textField = //setup field
    textField.tag = i;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
}
```

then when you want to reference a field later

```
UITextField *textField6 = [self.view viewWithTag:6];
UITextField *textField18 = [self.view viewWithTag:18];
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray* tfArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

    [self.view addSubview:textField];
    [tfArray addObject:textField];

}
```

if you want to reference a field:

the 6th textfield is for example:  `(UITextField*)tfArray[5];`